# Flutter - Set target file base on Android product flavors

Tags: android, flutter, android-productflavors

Currently I am using **Flutter** to build my application.

### Background

I have followed some guide on building different environments entry files:
https://iirokrankka.com/2018/03/02/separating-build-environments/
which create `main_dev.dart` and `main_prod.dart`.

Also I have learnt to build flavor for both iOS and Android:
https://medium.com/@salvatoregiordanoo/flavoring-flutter-392aaa875f36
which now I can use `--flavor <FLAVOR>` in the command to build different flavor application.

Now I have encountered a problem when I try to combine two skills.

---

### Target Result

Below is what I would like to achieve:

`development` flavor -> `main_dev.dart` entry file
`production` flavor -> `main_prod.dart` entry file

---

### Problem Encounter

in iOS side, I can target the entry file in .xcconfig file like following:

```
// ios/Flutter/development.xcconfig

#include "Generated.xcconfig"

FLUTTER_TARGET=lib/main_dev.dart
```

I know I can add `-t lib/main_dev.dart` after `flutter run` command.
However I would like to ask if there is any solution to set
the flutter target file in Android side inside flavor config?

Appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to ask if there is any solution to set the flutter target
>   file in Android side inside flavor config?

I don't know the equal of FLUTTER_TARGET for Android flavor. I would to like to learn that too.

But, `flutter run -t` is not the only option here. When you open a Flutter project (the root project) with Android Studio you will have a default run/debug configuration like below:

[image]

When you click **Edit Configurations** below screen will appear:

[image]

There you can set **Build flavor** and **Dart entrypoint**. Obviously, you can create multiple configurations for each flavor.

Reference: https://cogitas.net/creating-flavors-of-a-flutter-app/

So, that's a solution for Flutter in Android Studio. For VSCode, I have a workaround. I'm using **-t** parameter. But I have it automated by VSCode. Under **.vscode/launch.json** I have configurations like below:

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "GoodOne",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "args": ["--flavor",
                "good",
                "-t",
                "./lib/main-good.dart"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "BadOne",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "args": ["--flavor",
                "bad",
                "-t",
                "./lib/main-bad.dart"
            ]
        }
]
```

With this, you can run your flavors by just pressing **F5** and choose your config at the upper-left corner.

Again, this is not an exact answer to OP's question, but some workarounds.

Comment: Maybe not the right question, but I was looking for this answer, thanks.